# Fatal exception AsyncTask connection to phpmyadmin

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to do a log in an app that connects with `phpmyadmin`. When I start the app I get an exception.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText fname;
EditText lname;
EditText username;
EditText password;
EditText location;
EditText contact;

Button btnreg;
Button btncancel;

// url to create new product
private static String url_new_user = "http://192.168.0.1XX/android_test/newUser.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Edit Text
    fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fname);
    lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lname);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    location = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addr);
    contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact);


    // Create button
    btnreg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreg);
    btncancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncancel);

    // button click event
    btnreg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });

    btncancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Registering New User..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String Firstname = fname.getText().toString();
        String Lastname = lname.getText().toString();
        String Username = username.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
        String Address = location.getText().toString();
        String Contact = contact.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", Firstname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", Lastname));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", Address));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("contact", Contact));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_new_user,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat from response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created a user
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create user
                Log.d("failed to create user", json.toString());

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

}

and this is the `logcat`:
08-25 16:48:30.499: E/JSON Parser(1410): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    ...
    if (success == 1) {
        return "hooray";
    }
    ...
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    pDialog.dismiss();
    if (file_url != null) {
        // successfully created a user
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        // closing this screen
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aleksander are you connected to the internet? Is internet permission added?

Comment: yes im connected and internet permission added, i forgot the exeption is also showing----- 08-25 16:48:30.499: E/JSON Parser(1410): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
08-25 16:48:30.509: W/dalvikvm(1410): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)

Comment: @Aleksander well enter the url manually and check what's the output in the browser. It seems it's either showing you an error or there's some html code that can't be parsed by JSON (namely <br/>).

Comment: the output in the browser is {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}. ------I dont know what do you i am trying connecting android with phpmyadmin for 3 days now.

Comment: @Aleksander the problem is in php then. Please ask another question since this one seems to be unrelated to your problem.

Comment: can you please recomend a good question. thx for all your help

Comment: Post your new question and tag it with [tag:php]. Also include the code from `newUser.php` and the full error message.